# DA4R ACC Document User Permissions

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I have a web app that allows users to submit Design Automation for Revit work items via the APS APIs. I have an automation that begins with opening a file from Autodesk Construction Cloud using the following code:

```
ModelPath cloudModelPath = ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath(ModelPathUtils.CloudRegionUS, ProjectGuid, ModelGuid);

OpenOptions openOptions = new OpenOptions();
openOptions.AllowOpeningLocalByWrongUser = true;
openOptions.Audit = false;
openOptions.IgnoreExtensibleStorageSchemaConflict = true;

Document doc = rvtApp.OpenDocumentFile(cloudModelPath, openOptions);
```

I have found that this works fine for user A (me) but not for user B, even using the exact same model (and thus Project GUID and Model GUID). User B's work item fails with the following lines on the report:

```
Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.RevitServerUnauthorizedException: You are unauthorized to access this hub/project or the hub/project doesn't exist. Detail is One or more errors occurred.
    at Autodesk.Revit.DB.ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath(String region, Guid projectGuid, Guid modelGuid)
```

What's confusing to me is that I have confirmed that user B has access to the hub and project in question. Otherwise, he wouldn't be able to select the file from ACC and get access the correct GUIDs in the first place. The hub/project certainly exists, which leads me to thinking there's a genuine permissions error somewhere else and this exception isn't pointing me to it.

Are there any other permissions required for a DA4R user to avoid the RevitServerUnauthorizedException other than hub/project access? The Revit Core Engine (2022) is running at this point so it doesn't seem like a license thing.

Comment: Are you passing 3 legged token? What is the reason for `AllowOpeningLocalByWrongUser`?

Comment: Yes, passing a 3 legged token. I'm not sure if `AllowOpeningLocalByWrongUser` is necessary but I included it just to make sure that wasn't the cause. The error occurs on the `ModelPath` creation instead of the actual `OpenDocumentFile` function, so I don't think that setting is affecting anything.

Comment: Try removing the `AllowOpeningLocalByWrongUser` and confirm that you are passing the token like in the [blog](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-api-supports-revit-cloud-model). After you have done that and if it still fails, please share a workitem id.

Comment: Tried removing; no change. I can confirm I am passing the token correctly; it does work for some users and not others after all.

ID of example failed work item: 39c73eba05bb47f5b61862c36ce2be41

Comment: One quick question while Rahul is helping verify, can you share us the user B's folder permission which including the RCW, need to make sure User B has full permission to that folder. You can also compare the differences between User A and B.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. I didn't make the connection that opening a file directly from ACC required higher permissions (edit) than than downloading to the DA4R runtime with a signed download URL (view). This makes sense to me now and I can change my workflow to accommodate. Thank you both for your help.